# What is the exponential map from the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})\ltimes_\textrm{ad}\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ to its Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, inner-product, matrix-exponential

$\DeclareMathOperator\ad{ad}\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}\DeclareMathOperator\Exp{Exp}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\sl{\mathfrak{sl}}$Let $G:=\SL(2, C) \ltimes_{\Ad} \SL(2,C)$, where $\Ad_X(Y)=XYX^{-1}$ for all $X, Y \in \SL(2,C)$. It is known that $G$ is a Lie group and its Lie algebra is given by  $g:=\sl(2, C) \ltimes_{\ad} \sl(2,C)$, where $\ad_x(y)=[x,y]=xy-yx$ for all $x, y \in \sl(2,C)$. Its exponential map is given by $\Exp: g \rightarrow G$, by $\Exp(x,y)=(e^x, \phi(x,y))$, where $e$ is exponential map from $\sl(2,C)$ to $\SL(2,C)$ and  $\phi$ is map from $g$ to $\SL(2,C)$. Is it possible to calculate the map $\phi$ explicitly in this case?

Comment: I did not think to deeply about it so maybe this is non-sense but at first glance it seems that the explicit form of $\phi$ is what the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula tries to achieve. (Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)

Comment: Ehm after I typed this I am starting to think that maybe it is even simpler and $\phi(x, y)$ is simply $e^{[x, y]}$. But I guess you already thought of that and dismissed it for some reason. Can you elaborate about what your thoughts were?

Comment: I don't think  that the suggested ($^{[,]}$) map is the required exponential map. In article "A method for approximation of the exponential map in semidirect
product of matrix Lie groups and some applications"  in proof of Thm 3.2 it is given that $Exp(x,0)=(e^x, I)$ and $Exp(0,x)=(I, e^x)$, where $I$ is identity matrix. But in case $Exp(x,y)=(e^x, e^{[x,y]})$, $Exp(0,x)=(I, I)$ which is not correct.

Comment: There is an isomorphism $\varphi\colon\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\rtimes\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\to \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)\times \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C):(g,h)\mapsto (h,gh)$, where the product in the semidirect product is defined by $(g_1,h_1)*(g_2,h_2):=(g_1h_1g_2h_1^{-1},h_1h_2)$. Tracking the isomorphism should give you a formula for the exponential.

Comment: Let  is isomorphism between  $SL_2(C) \rtimes SL_2(C)$ and $SL_2(C) \times SL_2(C)$ and $\Phi$ is induced isomorphism between $sl_2(C) \rtimes sl_2(C)$ and $sl_2(C) \times sl_2(C)$. Let $exp$ be exponential map from $sl_2(C) \times sl_2(C)$ to $SL_2(C) \times SL_2(C).$  Then the required exponential map is given by following composition   $  ^{-1} \circ exp \circ \Phi$ ?